# Lambda expression to obtain a list of types from the attributes of other types

Tags: c#, lambda

I often find myself needing to compose a list of items from attributes of another list of items.
An approach I take is often similar to the following:

```
    public class MyClass
    {
        public Guid Identifier { get; set; }
        public byte[] Bytes { get; set; }
        public int ForeignKey { get; set; }

        public static List<MyClass> AllMyClass { get; }
    }

    private List<Guid> GetIdentifiers(int foreignKey)
    {
        List<Guid> identifiers = new List<Guid>();
        foreach (var item in MyClass.AllMyClass.FindAll(c => c.ForeignKey == foreignKey)
        {
            identifiers.Add(item.Identifier);
        }
        return identifiers;
    }
```

Now, is there any faster/simpler way of implementing this with a lamda expression? As in, I'd like to condense the operation into one line:

```
List<Guid> identifiers = MyClass.AllMyClass.MagicExpression(c => c.ForeignKey == foreignKey);
```

In addition, would such as expression be possible for the .NET 2.0 framework?

Comment: I don't think lambda expressions are available with the .NET framework 2.0

Comment: @Kane - lambdas are a language feature, not a framework feature. I think it is possible to use lambdas while targeting 2.0 using the C# 3\4 compilers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that something like that will work :

```
List<Guid> identifiers = MyClass.AllMyClass.Where(x => x.ForeignKey == foreignKey).Select(x => x.Identifier).ToList();
```

More over, they're no lambda expressions in .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

`MagicExpression` is usually called `Where`.

And, as far as I know, there is neither LINQ, nor lambdas, nor extension methods in .Net 2.0; so, answer to second question is probably no.

Comment: Yeah, the product I'm working on is built with .net 2.0 and used on workstations from Win2000 to Win7-64bit. Upgrading the framework would mean ditching the Win2000 workstations... so that not happening until the product owner decides.

Comment: @MoSlo If you wanted to hack around a bit, you could still implement a static `Extensions.Where` method taking a list and a delegate and use [anonymous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yw3tz5k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead of lambdas. That wouldn't reinvent the wheel, just mount a today's wheel to a vintage car and see if it brings advantages...

Comment: @MoSlo If Lee's right, you don't even have to work around lambdas. That makes sense, since in the end they are delegates, too. You just don't have LINQ available.